# Time and Date Pop up is HUGE

Tags: windows-10

How can you reduce the size of the Time and Date window?  The pop up takes up a huge chunk of the screen.  This is what I get when I click on the Time and Date tool.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your title has nothing to do with your question.Please fix that or you probably won't get an answer. Read [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: Are you using any sort of display scaling?

Comment: yes, i had eye surgery and needed larger font temporarily. ive changed back to normal now. it still seems to large to me?

Answer (score 1):

This is the entire clock popup on Windows 10 1607, at 100% display scaling.

[image]

Including the task bar, it’s 777 pixels in height.

You can collapse the lower area using the “Hide agenda setup” button, although it’s probably labeled differently because you have a calendar set up.

You also have an additional time zone visible, adding more height. You can hide additional clocks by right-clicking on the clock; from there, select “Adjust date/time” → “Add clocks for different time zones”. With the agenda visible, this results in a height of 837 pixels at 100%.

And last but not least you have display scaling set to 125%. The resulting popup is large enough to cover almost all of your (presumed) 1080 pixels in display height.

Comment: To change Display Scaling, right-click on the Desktop and choose Display Settings. If you have multiple monitors, choose the monitor you're interested in, then use the slider "Change the size of text, apps, and other items: " The default is 125%.  My PC shows a change in Time/Date popup size from 100->125->150 , but then it's as tall as it can get.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I beg to differ, scaling goes up to at least 300% (on my 4K TV).  // He might not want to change the scaling levels, depending on the physical display size and his vision.

Comment: ive changed scaling to normal and removed additional time zone.  still seems to large to me?

Comment: Unless you decide to switch to the legacy style (see Elie’s answer on that), you’ll have to accept it. If you haven’t done so, collapse the agenda area. It’s very large.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the theme and size of the date and time layout by the following Regedit key

First navigate to regedit by pressing windows keys + R and type regedit

Then navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell
```

And create a new DWORD (32bit) value and name it UseWin32TrayClockExperience and set its value to 1 .

Comment: This wouldn't fix the scaling issue the author has.

Comment: Trying this as well.  Rebooting